# create help file in txt from a ms word document

Tags: vba, perl, parsing, ms-word, win32ole

I need to create a txt file from a ms word document. The txt file will be used as a help document for my user interface and therefore it needs to be in a special format. Is there any third party software that I can use to read a ms word doc and create a text file from it in a certain format? Or, can I use PERL to read a word doc in a way where I can extract the headers, tables and section headings as specified in the word doc. I need to read the word document and while I am parsing it, I need to figure out a way to say if the line parsed from the ms word doc is a table content or a section heading? Or is there any other way of doing it?

Comment: What's that special format? Describe what exactly you want to do, instead of just wanting 'a text file'!

Answer (score 0):

I have a lot more familiarity with parsing HTML, so I would suggest that you translate your Word docs into HTML first using [`MSWord::ToHTML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/MSWord%3a%3aToHTMLL) or some equivalent module.

Then you can use one of the myriad of HTML Parsing modules out there, like [`Mojo::DOM`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo%3a%3aDOM) to parse out your data and its styling.  There's an 8 minute video on how to use the latter module [`Mojocast Episode 5`](http://mojocasts.com/e5).